# How to create variable buffers with nearest mean distance radius value

Tags: qgis, buffer, expression, proximity

Given a point geometries collection, I would like to use an expression which:

1. Find the 4 points nearest to each other
2. Create the buffer for each group of 4 points with the radius distance value corresponding to mean distance to the 4 nearest points.

I add a screenshot representing the expected result:

[image]

Comment: So, since you have an expression... what is your question?

Comment: What does not work with your expression which seems to be a good start? Rather than buffer you can make_circle(...)

Comment: This is for visualization purpose, or you need a individual buffer layer?

Comment: Visualization purpose

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
buffer(
    $geometry,
    array_mean(  -- lengths mean
        array_foreach(
            overlay_nearest( -- get nearest points
                'CONTENIDORS_GEO',
                $geometry,
                limit:=4
            ),
            length(
                make_line(
                    $geometry,
                    @element
                )
            )
        )
    )   
)
```

[image]

Comment: So basically OP had it correct, except for the outermost part of the expression?